# ¿ Como solucionar problemas en cordova?

Tags: android, cordova

Hola estoy tratando de correr un proyecto de cordova en mi dispositivo y al correr `cordova run android --device` la consola me muestra en siguiente error:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/home/diana/Android/sdk
 JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
 Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
```

Tengo todo bien configurado, react native me funciona perfectamente.
¿ que significa este error de cordova ?
Graias

Comment: Que versión de jdk tienes?

Comment: Hola @anonimo al correr java -version me muestra lo siguiente: `java version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode)`